# selenium POM framework and TestNG wait Time

Tags: java, maven, selenium

In my Test script have to write waiFor(5) for every excution, else Test fails.
Am using POM, and have separate class.

```
  @Test(priority=2)      
    public void TestMedical() throws InterruptedException {
        waitFor(5);
        MedicalPage medicalpage = new MedicalPage(driver); 
        waitFor(5);
        medicalpage.PhysicianName(Repo.getProperty("fName"));
        medicalpage.seteditableLastName(Repo.getProperty("lName"));
        waitFor(5);
        medicalpage.setPhone(Repo.getProperty("Phone"));
        waitFor(5);
        medicalpage.setEmail(Repo.getProperty("Email"));
    }
```

This is my Login Page (Object)-

```
// Created methods in this page, and using Testng trying to call all the below methods. But getting failure message Unable to Locate Element, If there is no wait time watFor(5). With Wait time its running fine.In base page have explicit wait time method, but its not working. After input the data in text field when i click on submit button page is doing some Java Script or Ajax.
```

Ajax call takes 60 sec max.

```
          driver.findElement(firstName).click();
          driver.findElement(editableFirstName).clear();
          driver.findElement(editableFirstName).click();
          driver.findElement(editableFirstName).sendKeys(fName);

   }
```

Comment: Some more information would be helpful: how does the test fail (e.g. with what kind of Exception), is there a sample page online to have a look at the page source code, is the page doing some JavaScript stuff (e.g. AJAX) when a input element is filled,...

Comment: Well the easy thing without any other details provided, try an implicit wait for 5 seconds. But this is not the ideal solution at all...

Comment: I don't remember exactly but there was some `setSpeed()` method which delays execution all the latter statements by delay specified.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  Then remove all the waitfor's.  An implicit wait will wait up to whatever time limit you give it, but will continue the script as soon as it receives a response, so there's no forced delay.

Comment: I should add, in case you're not familiar with it, that the implicit wait only needs to be set once, preferably soon after the driver itself is initialized.

Comment: @BillHileman, thanks for suggestion. Tried but getting error message "Unable to locate the Element". but if put waitFor(5) in every execution then its run fine.

Comment: @AlvaHenrik Application is in shadow environment, can't share the link. Yes the page doing some JavaScript stuff (e.g. AJAX) when a input element is filled.

Comment: @SumitBanerjee: try something like after filling your input `driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: @AlvaHenrik Yes using AJAX submit the data into database, so have to wait for seconds.

Comment: Just two advices from my side: I experienced strange behaviour when using implicitlyWait and WebDriverWait together, so we set implicitlyWait to 0 right after driver initialization. The other thing is that for one application we are forced to really wait for the AJAX calls and the corresponding JavaScript to finish before we can continue with the next action, so we implemented a method that wait's for the visual indicator of that application to disappear. That was the only way we got it working in a stable manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added try - catch, works fine now

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(XYZ);
         boolean clicked = false;
         do{
                try {
                    element.click();
                } catch (WebDriverException e) {
                    continue;
                } finally {
                    clicked = true;
                }
        } while (!clicked);;
```